# What do you call a robe that's parted in the middle and is longer in the back?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, image-identification

I have a reference picture of what I'm actually talking about, it's the.. coat/robe that the elf is wearing below. It's got like this tear-drop skirt, and I'm not sure whether 'coat' or 'robe' is more appropriate or if there's something better.

[image: Elf]

Comment: Fashion experts might well have a specific word for this. I wouldn't call it a robe, but rather a jacket or coat. A robe is usually not something to be worn in public or outside, and that looks like you would wear it in public.

Comment: Looks like it is modeled on the "tailcoat".

Comment: @Mitch It's tough because "coat" seems to imply something heavier, whereas the item he's wearing looks like it's made out of silk almost. Thinking in a more fantasy reality, robes are worn outside pretty much all the time. But, with the pointed shoulders, coat is still probably the better choice as you said..

Comment: 'Elvencoat' actually occurs on the internet, and [some](https://www.google.com/search?q=elvencoat&rlz=1C1ASRM_enGB617GB618&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_wpnRgtriAhXsURUIHUJqBckQ_AUIEigD&biw=1659&bih=930#imgrc=QxtEhk3hYXgqBM:) ... [examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=elvencoat&rlz=1C1ASRM_enGB617GB618&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_wpnRgtriAhXsURUIHUJqBckQ_AUIEigD&biw=1659&bih=930#imgrc=bEJzBNM01_4ajM:) are of this style. [Google image search]

Comment: It does seem similar to the men's jacket that has tails, except that the back part is all one piece.  It looks a lot like The Little Prince's regal robe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a hobbyist fashion designer and seamstress, there is no specific term for this article to account for the tapered hemline.

Any way you’d call this item, whether coat, sheath, etc, if you wanted to indicate it has tapered hemline, you’d have to expressly call it out.